# SOLIDITY CODING -- _totalSupply 0

Tags: solidity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irqWi.png)

Add 4 lines of code ALL of it are success!

But check wallet.ethereum.org can't find LC TOKEN and also ropsten.etherscan does not appear to be a valid Token Contract address

Comment: OpenZeppelin standardtoken    adds 4 lines   uint public constant _totalSupply = 1000000;

string public constant symbol = "LC";
string public constant name = "leocyber Token";
string public constant decimals = 3;


something wrong the following totalSupply_
  uint256 public totalSupply_;

  /**
  * @dev Total number of tokens in existence
  */
  function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
    return totalSupply_;

Comment: i try again take out the underscore in between 'constant' and 'totalSupply'. please check second one images![enter image description here][2]

Comment: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7rVW.png

Answer (score 0):

You have an underscore in between 'constant' and 'totalSupply'.  As a result, you have a variable, displayed above decimals, that is named 'constant_totalSupply'.  If you remove this underscore, I think this code should work as expected.